# media query won't work on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

So I want the link at the bottom of my page to have a bigger font-size on screens smaller than 580px (which should obviously be nearly all phone screens).

If I check it in dev tools and change the width it looks fine like this [image]

but once I use 'phone screen mode' and for example iPhone 5 it's back to the normal font-size of 25px, what the media query should've increased?
[image]

```css
body{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
/****************************/

img{
    width: 96%;
    margin: 2%;
}


/*********** Footer Section **************/


#link-back a, #link-back p{
 color: #666666;
 font-family: Raleway;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
    float: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-size: 25px;
    margin: 10px 0 -10px 0;
    display: block;
}

#link-back::before
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background:#666666;
  opacity: .4;
}

:hover#link-back a {
    color: red;
}

#copyright p, #copyright{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    font-size: 13px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 580px){
    #link-back a, #link-back p{
        font-size: 45px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    #link-back::before{
        height: 80px;
    {
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Typographic Pairing</title>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/heart.png">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="http://heartcube.co.uk/typographic-pairing/project2.jpg" alt="project 2">
    <p id="copyright">&copy; 2017 Bettina Bremm</p>
  
    <p id="link-back"><a href="../work/index.html" onclick="self.close()">back to heartcube</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your `viewport` meta tag ...?

Comment: well that was stupid of me and solved very quick, don't know how I forgot it, thanks man, I wouldn't have noticed for days

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe noticed, the meta tag was missing for the viewport!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```